# New Order #3: 5 8 6

Tags: code-golf, sequence

### Introduction *(may be ignored)*

Putting all positive numbers in its regular order (1, 2, 3, ...) is a bit boring, isn't it? So here is a series of challenges around permutations (reshuffelings) of all positive numbers. This is the third challenge in this series (links to the [first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181268) and [second](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181825/) challenges).

In this challenge, we will arrange the natural numbers in rows of increasing length in such a way that the sum of each row is a prime. What I find really amazing about this, is that every natural number has a place in this arrangement. No numbers are skipped!

This visualisation of this arrangement looks like this:

```
row             numbers             sum
1                  1                  1
2                2   3                5
3              4   5   8             17
4            6   7   9  15           37
5          10 11  12  13  21         67
6        14  16 17  18  19  23      107
etc.
```

We can read the elements from the rows in this triangle. The first 20 elements are: 1, 2, 3, 4, [***5, 8, 6***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXl3Qej1tjM), 7, 9, 15, 10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19 (*yes, there is a New Order song hidden in this sequence*).

Since this is a "pure sequence" challenge, the task is to output \$a(n)\$ for a given \$n\$ as input, where \$a(n)\$ is [A162371](http://oeis.org/A162371).

### Task

Given an integer input \$n\$, output \$a(n)\$ in integer format.

\$a(n)\$ is defined as the \$n\$th element of the lexicographically earliest permutation of the natural numbers such that, when seen as a triangle read by rows, for n>1 the sums of rows are prime numbers. Since the first lexicographical permutation of natural numbers starts with 1, \$a(1)\$ is 1. Note that by this definition \$a(1) = 1\$ and \$a(1)\$ is ***not*** required to be prime. This is OEIS sequence [A162371](https://oeis.org/A162371).

*Note: 1-based indexing is assumed here; you may use 0-based indexing, so \$a(0) = 1; a(1) = 2\$, etc. Please mention this in your answer if you choose to use this.*

### Test cases

```
Input | Output
---------------
1     |  1
5     |  5
20    |  19
50    |  50
78    |  87
123   |  123
1234  |  1233
3000  |  3000
9999  |  9999
29890 |  29913
```

### Rules

- Input and output are integers (your program should at least support input and output in the range of 1 up to 32767)
- Invalid input (0, floats, strings, negative values, etc.) may lead to unpredicted output, errors or (un)defined behaviour.
- Default [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.
- [Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answers in bytes wins

Comment: Can we output the sequence infinitely, or return a generator instead?

Comment: Err, 1 is not a prime

Comment: @JoKing about a(1)=1: I'll add that. That is indeed the exception. This is stated clearly in the OEIS entry, buy I failed tot mention it explicitly. I'll add it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @JoKing note that the definition of the sequence only requires the sum of the row to be prime for n>1. Since the sequence is the first lexicographical permutation of the natural numbers, a(1) comes out as 1. So indeed, 1 is not prime but the challenge or the definition of the sequence doesn't say or require 1 to be prime...

Comment: @JoKing this is a "pure sequence" challenge. So I won't allow to output the entire sequence. For a given n, you need to output a(n) and a(n) alone.

Comment: Related sequence: [A075348](http://oeis.org/A075348).

Comment: @jimmy23013 Nice find! Ik would have chosen that sequence if I found it earlier. It's more elegant in my opinion. A big issue is of couse that the New Order song "5 8 6" is not part of this sequence... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 22 bytes

```
!¡§ḟ(ΛoṗΣtü¤≤LCN:)`-Nø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9odXNr//8hwqHCp@G4nyjOm2/huZfOo3TDvMKk4omkTENOOilgLU7DuP///zc4) I was honestly somewhat surprised that `CN` worked as intended here. Heavily inspired by [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182353/33208).

#### Explanation

```
!¡λḟ(ΛoṗΣtü¤≤LCN:⁰)-⁰N)ø  (Expanded; let X denote the argument.)
!                         Take element X of
 ¡                         the list created by repeatedly applying this function
                           to the prior list and appending its output,
                       ø    starting with an empty list:
                   -⁰N      Take the list of natural numbers not contained in the
                            argument,
   ḟ                         and find the first element such that
     ΛoṗΣ                     all sums are prime of
                :⁰                the element appended to the argument,
              CN                 cut into lengths of 1, 2, 3, etc.,
          ü¤≤L                  filtered for increasing length,
         t                     with its first element dropped.
```

Comment: A late, but relatively short answer. The sortest to be exactly. Well done! You win!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;®»ṀƊSÆn_S
ẎṀ©+LRḟẎḣL;Ç$ṭ
1Ç¡Fị@
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/60LpDux/ubDjWFXy4LS8@mOvhrj4g99BKbZ@ghzvmg3g7FvtYH25XebhzLZfh4fZDC90e7u52@P//v7kFAA)** - very slow as it builds n rows first, for a faster version which doesn't, at 37 bytes, [try this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/60LpDux/ubDjWFXy4LS8@mOvhrj4g99BKbZ@ghzvmg3g7FvtYH25XebhzLZfh4XY3H5tDm49tOrTf7eHubof///8bWVpYGgAA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>80</s> 77 bytes

```perl6
{({$!=@_;+(1...{$_∉$!&&(|$!,$_).rotor(1..*).one.sum.is-prime-1})}...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1qjWkXR1iHeWlvDUE9Pr1ol/lFHp4qimppGjYqijkq8pl5Rfkl@EUhSS1MvPy9Vr7g0Vy@zWLegKDM3VdewVrNWDyQVrRIfW/u/OLFSIU0jztDAQNP6PwA)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                  }  # Anonymous code block
 (                        ...*)[$_]   # Index into the infinite sequence
  {                      }   # Where each element is
   $!=@_;  # Save the list of previous elements into $!
   +(1...{             })    # Return the first number that
          $_∉$!         # Has not appeared in the list so far
          &&            # And
          (|$!,$_)      # The new sequence
          .rotor(1..*)  # Split into rows of increasing length
                        # And ignoring incomplete rows
          .one          # Have exactly one row
          .sum          # Where the sum
          .is-prime-1   # Is not prime (i.e. just the first row)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>122</s> 120 bytes

```hs
import Data.Numbers.Primes
l%a|(p,q)<-splitAt l a,(s,k:t)<-span(not.isPrime.(+sum p))q=p++k:(l+1)%(s++t)
((1:1%[2..])!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBC4IwGIbv/YoJCd/Y59i0KEUPQdeiu0gsMBpua7p167@b@cLzHB54XyoMvTHzrK1/T5GcVVT8@rGPfgr8Nmnbh41J1Rc8jrTOgjc6niIxRCEEHKq4RuXAvSPXYX1wYOFjiad0bDxjQwWGSZpCYCzSzbMBkJVM25zzjiYJna3SjjTEKn@5Ez9pF0kLLpP43C6mX1dnrcQ95gL3Ag9HlHnxZ4eFEALLZZiXx1J03fwD) (has an extra 2 bytes for `f=`)

EDIT: Now uses 0-based indexing to save 2 bytes. Thanks @wastl for pointing that out, I must have missed it in the OP.

This was very fun to write! The helper function `%` takes a length `l` and a list of values it can use `a`. It returns an infinite list of values for the sequence. The length is one less than the length of the current triangle row and the list is infinite and pre-sorted. First we just yield the first `l` values from `a` and then look through the rest of a until we find the first (smallest) value that makes the sum prime. We break up the list around that value using `span` and some pattern matching. Now all we have to do is yield that new value and recur with the next line length `l+1` and the remaining values in `a`. For the final result we prepend 1 (special case for n=0) and index into it with `!!`.

Comment: I think you can remove the `0:` as the challenge states you can use 0-based indexing.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>111</s>  110 bytes

```javascript
n=>{for(g=n=>{for(d=n;n%--d;);},i=l=0;i--||(k=s=0,i=l++),n--;g[k]=s+=r=k)for(;g[++k]|g(!i*++s)|d>1;);return r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxNDoIwEAXgvafAhUlrrRaQoGmGixgXxkKDkNa06MZydqT@xjqrl/flzelwPdijqc8dVVqUQwWDguJWaYMkvJMAxdWMUsEx7xc1tMB4TalzqAELzDeE4IWilMtdswdLwECD/XQsCGn2TqJpPSfEYieKeHxjyu5iVGT64aiV1W25bLVEFYoxjvytVlE8@aXsS1lACXuaX23D2dcyFli@@dgmDyxO0gf6n0n6j2uvTww1ZYy91MfhDg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 46 bytes

```
S©‘æR®Ḥ‘¤_®ḟ;F¥Ṃ
FLḤRḟFḣ0ịLƊ;ç¥µW
1;Ç$⁸½Ḥ¤¡Fị@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/40MpHDTMOLws6tO7hjiVA5qEl8SDmfGu3Q0sf7mzicvMBigcBBdwe7lhs8HB3t8@xLuvDyw8tPbQ1nMvQ@nC7yqPGHYf2AhUdWnJooRtQgcP///@NDQwMAA)

Times out for large n on tio, but works there for all but the last two examples.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>242</s> <s>228</s> <s>226</s> 211 bytes

```lua
s={}u={}i=0 n=0+...while i<n do
n=n-i
x,S=1,0
for j=1,i do
while u[x]do x=x+1 end
s[j]=x
S=S+x
u[x]=0
end
while u[x]or p do
x=x+1
d=S+x
p=F
for c=2,d-1 do
p=p or d%c<1
end
end
i=i+1
s[i]=x
u[x]=0
end
print(s[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NCsIwEITv@xS5CEp/SLwJ7tUX6DH0IE3FLWUbGosB8dljNh50YWDZmfl23q4pBXy9tyxCrRh11bbt807zqOjMyi3AyA1BrDs0tYbbsqopbyTWN7fZ2LtFRYyVUSM7CHbqMUKHXRVBXNQg9188Q7wASgdcCXq8FPqAx9o1RmyPXuWL2w1nUwgiQsqdYEl@/NH9SvzYB8v9IaV0yvMB)