# New Order #6: Easter Egg

Tags: code-golf, sequence

### Introduction *(may be ignored)*

Putting all positive integers in its regular order (1, 2, 3, ...) is a bit boring, isn't it? So here is a series of challenges around permutations (reshuffelings) of all positive integers. This is the sixth challenge in this series (links to the [first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181268), [second](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181825), [third](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182348), [fourth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182810) and [fifth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183186) challenge).

This challenge has a mild Easter theme (because it's Easter). I took my inspiration from this highly decorated (and in my personal opinion rather ugly) goose egg.

[image: Decorated goose egg]

It reminded me of the [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral), where all positive integers are placed in a counter-clockwise spiral. This spiral has some interesting features related to prime numbers, but that's not relevant for this challenge.

[image: Ulam spiral]

We get to this challenge's permutation of positive integers if we take the numbers in the Ulam spiral and trace all integers in a *clockwise* turning spiral, starting at 1. This way, we get:

```
1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 25, 24, 23, etc.
```

If you would draw both of the spirals, you'd get some sort of an infinite [mesh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpghMn2Vg1c) of (egg shell) spirals (*note the [New Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Order_(band)) reference there*).

This sequence is present in the OEIS under number [A090861](https://oeis.org/A090861). Since this is a "pure sequence" challenge, the task is to output \$a(n)\$ for a given \$n\$ as input, where \$a(n)\$ is [A090861](https://oeis.org/A090861).

### Task

Given an integer input \$n\$, output \$a(n)\$ in integer format, where \$a(n)\$ is [A090861](https://oeis.org/A090861).

*Note: 1-based indexing is assumed here; you may use 0-based indexing, so \$a(0) = 1; a(1) = 6\$, etc. Please mention this in your answer if you choose to use this.*

### Test cases

```
Input | Output
---------------
1     |  1
5     |  3
20    |  10
50    |  72
78    |  76
123   |  155
1234  |  1324
3000  |  2996
9999  |  9903
29890 |  29796
```

### Rules

- Input and output are integers.
- Your program should at least support input in the range of 1 up to 32767).
- Invalid input (0, floats, strings, negative values, etc.) may lead to unpredicted output, errors or (un)defined behaviour.
- Default [I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.
- [Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answers in bytes wins

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>16 14 11 10 9</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Lynn (mod-2; logical NOT; add to self: `Ḃ¬+` -> bitwise OR with 1:`|1`)

```
|1×r)ẎQi
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer, `n`, which yields an integer, `a(n)`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/G8PD0Is2Hu/oCM////29oAAA)** (very inefficient since it goes out to layer \$\lceil\frac n2\rceil\$)

An 11-byte version, `½‘|1×rƲ€ẎQi`, completes all but the largest test case in under 30s - [Try it at TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q3kcNM2oMD08vOrbpUdOah7v6AjP/H91zuB3Icf//31DHVMfIQMfUQMfcQsfQyBiETXSMDQwMdCyBAAA) - this limits the layers used to \$\lceil\frac{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor+1}2\rceil\$.

#### How?

The permutation is to take the natural numbers in reversed slices of lengths `[1,5,3,11,5,17,7,23,9,29,11,35,13,...]` - the odd positive integers interspersed with the positive integers congruent to five modulo six, i.e `[1, 2*3-1, 3, 4*3-1, 5, 6*3-1, 7, 8*3-1, 9, ...]`.

This is the same as concatenating and then deduplicating reversed ranges `[1..x]` of where `x` is the cumulative sums of these slice lengths (i.e. the maximum of each slice) - `[1,6,9,20,25,42,49,72,81,110,121,156,169,...]`, which is the odd integers squared interspersed with even numbers multiplied by themselves incremented, i.e. `[1*1, 2*3, 3*3, 4*5, 5*5, 6*7, 7*7,...]`.

Since the differences are all greater than 1 we can save a byte (the reversal) by building ranges `[x..k]` directly, where `k` is the 1-indexed index of the slice.

Due to this structure the permutation is a self-conjugate permutation, i.e. we know that \$P(n) = v \iff P(v) = n\$, so rather than finding the value at (1-indexed) index `n` (`|1×r)ẎQị@`) we can actually get the (1-indexed) index of the first occurrence of `n` (`|1×r)ẎQi`).

```
|1×r)ẎQi - Link: integer, n       e.g. 10
    )    - for each k in [1..n]:  vs = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10]
|1       -   bitwise-OR (k) with 1     [ 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9,11]
  ×      -   multiply (by k)           [ 1, 6, 9,20,25,42,49,72,81,110]
   r     -   inclusive range (to k)    [[1],[6..2],[9..3],[20..4],...,[110..10]]
     Ẏ   - tighten                     [1,6,5,4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,20,...,4,......,110,...,10]
      Q  - de-duplicate                [1,6,5,4,3,2,9,8,7,20,...,10,......,110,...82]
       i - first index with value (n)  20
```

Comment: Very nice. And you surpassed the MATL answer!

Comment: Tied now... :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I just realised I can do something sneaky here and save one byte :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Aww. That deserves one upvote :-)

Comment: 9 bytes: `|1×r)ẎQị@`

Comment: @Lynn I am actually just updating to a different 9 byter. Yours will prob make 8!

Comment: @Lynn yep, now at 8, thanks!

Comment: Sweet! This is a very nice answer :)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>46 45</s>  41 bytes

0-indexed.

```javascript
n=>((x=n**.5+1&~1)*2-(n<x*x+x)*4+3)*x+1-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc/BDoIwDAbgu0@xk9lGBt3GgCbiuxAEoyGbEWN28tUn3ljtqcn/tU3vw3tYx@ft8VI@XKY098n3Z85j76UsXaGPHy2kUdyfooxFFLIurNg6rXwag1/DMpVLuPKZa/YrxbQQrKoY04c8dyS3JDdA5oEuIKA1BLQdAQ0B2tj8hHP/os6ENTUhFgD2xCDSO7jVniDC37fYIWRbWmzSFw)

#### How?

This is based on the 1-indexed formula used in the example programs of [A090861](https://oeis.org/A090861).

\$x_n\$ is the layer index of the spiral, starting with \$0\$ for the center square:

$$x_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{n-1}+1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9NbsIwFIT3OcXssGlwY8cUUEVvkBVLmoUFBIJSOzJWr5@Oqchi5PfzzTz57n7d4xT7Ma18OF@mqcEexwI4otYlakPVlKXW1Ae1QVv@E1UJza3mVnOrudUbEtsXYXacMAOkQAqZ2pLYzQQ7zUvIVH5zBl22mgkmal4CpyAN9oa91TNBj2Gy4QXDS4ZZhlnWvAibE@m19FrSlrQlbWu0RftZFB2/7bH/QuPSTXVDCFEI4bGCllguUak13nL9DiOL4hT8IwwXNYSraNSPG0XM5vgsnzmd8FKlcEix91ch1ejOh@RiErWU6h56LxaLufr2rKfpDw)

\$k_n\$ is set to \$6\$ for the bottom part of each layer (including the center square), and to \$-2\$ everywhere else:

$$k_n=\begin{cases}
-2&\text{if }n\le 4{x_n}^2+2x_n\\
6&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/NboMwEITvPMXcYlPi4sX5a5v2CTjlmHJASciPUhsRVOXt6ThVOIzY9Xw7Iy71b33bdee2n/qwPwxDiTW2CbBFYTMUQhWUo2bUnFqgyv6JPIOla@laupauXZBYPglZ8YUZIAVSiNSSxGokuFk2IVLxGzN45fKRYKJlE/gK0uAu3J0dCd4Ik4UNwiZhljDLyZNwMZG3jreOtCPtSLsCVVK9J0nD3/ZYf0LdOZV1fzLNNYROKeUxhdVIU@Rmhpc4v0J0Rv5jDYcU92gKLXksX5gK3jDXSbIL/hauB3MNR1Wan7pVXSzpHuOjr1Femz5s@u7sj0qbtt5v@rrrVaG1uYSzV5PJOH17zsPwBw)

Then \$a_n\$ is given by:

$$a_n=8{x_n}^2+k_nx_n+2-n$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/NboMwEITvPMXcYqfg4sX5a0v7BDnlmHJA@Y9SGxFU5e3pmCocVuzsfjNrrvVvfd@1l6bLfNgf@n6NEtsE2KKwKQphFSzHmrHmrAWq9J/IU1huLbeWW8utXZBYPglZccIMkAIpRGpJYjUSVJaXEKn4jRl0uXwkmGh5CZyCNKiF2tmRoEeYLLwgvCTMEmY5eRIuJtLr6HWkHWlH2hWokuo9SY78bY/yE0tMoR5U67o7m@MthFYp5ZHBakynyM0ML7F/hehhItQEPko4eh/PkQziC5ngDXM9qDjN4JNkF/w93A7mFk5qbX7qRrXxeDu0wzuOymvThU3XXvxJadPU@01Xt50qtDbXcPFqMhm7b8@@7/8A)

Which can be translated into:

```javascript
n=>8*(x=(n-1)**.5+1>>1)*x+(n<=4*x*x+2*x?-2:6)*x+2-n
```

Making it 0-indexed saves 5 bytes right away:

```javascript
n=>8*(x=n**.5+1>>1)*x+(n<4*x*x+2*x?-2:6)*x+1-n
```

The formula can be further simplified by using:

$${x'}_n=2\times\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

which can be expressed as:

```javascript
x=n**.5+1&~1
```

leading to:

```javascript
n=>2*(x=n**.5+1&~1)*x+(n<x*x+x?-1:3)*x+1-n
```

and finally:

```javascript
n=>((x=n**.5+1&~1)*2-(n<x*x+x)*4+3)*x+1-n
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 60 bytes

```
8(s=⌊(⌊Sqrt[#-1]⌋+1)/2⌋)^2-#+2+If[#<=4s^2+2s,-2,6]s&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n27730Kj2PZRT5cGEAcXFpVEK@saxj7q6dY21NQ3AtKacUa6ytpG2p5p0co2tibFcUbaRsU6ukY6ZrHFav8DijLzShy00hX0HRSqDXVMdYwMdEwNdMwtdAyNjEHYRMfYwMBAxxIIdIwsLSwNav//BwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
Eq1YL!tPG=)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/37XQMNJHsSTA3Vbz/39DI2MA)

Very memory-inefficient. Prepending `X^k` makes it [more efficient](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyIu27XQMNJHsSTA3Vbz/38jSwtLAwA).

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 67 bytes

```cs
n=>8*(x=(int)Math.Sqrt(--n)+1>>1)*x+(n<4*x*x+2*x?-2:6)*x+1-n;int x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYu7CgIxEEV/ZcuZxEiyiIh52FlpZWEtYYPTjJiNMH8fs8WBey6cvJq8Ur/@OAfithukEjvHdFIgEYbj/dXe@8e3NjCGUbuUHCrRwOGgZIxZycXM5@N2OsN@NJP4Xj51yyeK1pPWwVnr8VmpLTfiBQoQou9/)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.8, <s>104</s> <s>74</s> <s>65</s> <s>60</s> 57 bytes

```python
lambda n:(-2,6)[n>4*(x:=(n**.5+1)//2)*x+2*x]*x+2+~n+8*x*x
```

Edit: Thanks to Johnathan Allan for getting it from 74 to 57 bytes!

This solution uses 0-based indexing.

Comment: Save 39 avoiding the imports, removing some redundant parentheses, and using `>` in place of `<=` and `x*x` in place of `x**2` ...like so: `def f(n):x=((n-1)**.5+1)//2;return 8*x**2+(-2,6)[n>4*x*x+2*x]*x+2-n` ...[TIO](https://tio.run/##FYjLDsIgEEV/heUMTC2PVkGjP9J0J8Rupg1igl@PcpOTc3KPb3nt7Fp7xiQSMF7rHYAHg1KeZmVwHO0tx/LJDIOlMy78mGSVVVlZ166Ble9HO/LGBZYEJb4LirRn0UtsLMDQTFbTrOniyVjXmchprSn8Rzb4oHHF9gM)

Comment: Awesome!  I will incorporate the edits. Made some changes before I saw your comment and got it down to 74 bytes.  Does it matter that yours returns floats?  I assume not...

Comment: Float representations of integers should be fine. Save some more [using Python 3.8 assignment](https://tio.run/##JYzLDoIwFAX3fkV3fXALbaFamsCPqAuMEkjkQrCLGuO3V4iTnJzMZpZ3GGYs3bKmvrmkZzfd7h1Bz6SBIz9jWwkWfcMYSs2FyG2meVEYLmJmRLzuJzFzIoqY@nkl4fEKZETCNFgwCqyCkwNtyn0VlEopqDfA1K5W3B/IxrKOGBj9@NZ@ab5lpi6wvcSBUNlSIP1fefoB) ...EDIT: make it [zero indexed](https://tio.run/##JYzLDoIwFET3fkV3fV1ACkjbBH5EXWC0kUQuBLuoMfrrtcRJTmZmc5aXv89Y6WWNrjvFxzBdrgNByzIFB37EvhYs2I6hEHkjS14UiosglQjnreQXpRZBhOjmlfjb05MRCdtDDaWB2kDbQqlUoqpAGWMgodPS2nC7IynLOqJn9G375kPzpJkGzzYTB0KzngJx/8vjDw)

Comment: Very cool. Feel free to make any further edits directly!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 53 bytes

A direct port of [Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183531/53748), go upvote that, and/or [J42161217's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183529/53748), and/or [Kapocsi's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183536/53748) :)

```python
lambda n:((x:=int(n**.5+1)&-2)*2-(n<x*x+x)*4+3)*x+1-n
```

0-indexed.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3LCsIwFET3fkVW5nVTTNLSJNh@iZuKFgv2ttQsIuK3xxQHDsxszqzv@FjQunXLY3fJz2G@3gaCgbEUugkjQyGqRmp@VIYLoxiek0gycVFLy0vTCvO4bCTeX5FMSNgJatAeag9tC9qYgrVgvPdQcKU553k4kJJ12y/oJ/TNl1ZFMw@R7SYOhKqeAhn/k@cf)**

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, <s>67</s> 57 bytes

This solution assumes 0-based indexing for the input values.

```
p&v-*8p00:+1g00:<
0:<@.-\+1*g00+*<|`
0g6*\`!8*2+00g4^>$:0
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=cCZ2LSo4cDAwOisxZzAwOjwKMDo8QC4tXCsxKmcwMCsqPHxgCjBnNipcYCE4KjIrMDBnNF4+JDow&input=Mjk4ODk)

**Explanation**

We start by calculating the "radius" at which the input *n* is found with a loop:

```
radius = 0
while n > 0
  radius += 1
  n -= radius*8
```

At the end of the loop, the previous value of *n* is the offset into the spiral at that radius:

```
offset = n + radius*8
```

We can then determine if we're on the top or bottom section of the spiral as follows:

```
bottom = offset >= radius*6
```

And once we have all these details, the spiral value is calculated with:

```
value = ((bottom?10:2) + 4*radius)*radius + 1 - offset
```

The radius is the only value that we need to store as a "variable", limiting it to a maximum value of 127 in Befunge-93, so this algorithm can handle inputs up to 65024.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 bytes

Port of Jonathan's Jelly solution. 1-indexed.

```
gUòÈ²+X*v)õÃcÔâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Z1XyyLIrWCp2KfXDY9Ti&input=OA)

```
gUòÈ²+X*v)õÃcÔâ     :Implicit input of integer U
g                   :Index into
 Uò                 :  Range [0,U]
   È                :  Map each X
    ²               :    Square X
     +X*            :    Add X multiplied by
        v           :    1 if X is divisible by 2, 0 otherwise
         )          :    Group result
          õ         :    Range [1,result]
           Ã        :  End map
            c       :  Flatten
             Ô      :    After reversing each
              â     :  Deduplicate
```

Comment: I just told Jonathan that `x+(1-x%2)` is `x|1` (saving a byte in Jelly), which this answer can also benefit from, I bet.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
!uṁS`…S*v1N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X7H04c7G4IRHDcuCtcoM/f7//29oAAA)

Instead of creating a range, an infinite list is created and nubbed. Hence, will be be very very slow for larger \$n\$

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 88 bytes

```cpp
#import<cmath>
int a(int n){int x=(sqrt(n-1)+1)/2;return x*(8*(x+(n>4*x*x+2*x))-2)+2-n;}
```

1-indexed; uses the formula on the OEIS page, but manipulated to save a few bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLboMwEDyHr1ilF5uHakxeBJJL1UO/ocrBMm5rCQwFIyGlfHu6BvqIpfWuxjvj9Vg2TfQu5e1BG1n2hYJc151tlajOiFVN3dpcVsJ@nD1tLAjidkOvLg0n0n22lpgopkFMH3nWKtu3BgafHHwyBMScN/7gDwH3B0ojTgMemWy8OXIltCEUrt6qs8XxKOveQp7D@sU0WH3BkyhlXwqrCqj7GXoeGiVnwCKydv0TWZmizLzVNFpfPYlOdXCC/QJpp9i9XhC6xiFsQ@AME8b@EELMk2nbhJAwhmCKC1vSQ8rGRWG@70/CMRydY@yw3qJmnPCNo6U7J8ESV@/TnZN4q1uYfNPIZxmm/HfODIJATzbc@7AMrS@TKfj46bXO/gWndwc/E879/00ZvdXyKyzzxts3)

Comment: Suggest `sqrt(n-1)/2+.5` instead of `(sqrt(n-1)+1)/2`

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
ƛ1⋎*›rṘ;fU?‹i
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B1%E2%8B%8E*%E2%80%BAr%E1%B9%98%3BfU%3F%E2%80%B9i&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Messy port